# why the pid not split to an array in bash

Tags: bash

I want to restart celery from server, because the celery has many process, to I write this script to query all process id and kill it:

```
#
# stop celery process
#
PID=`ps -ef|grep -w ${CELERY_PROGRAM_NAME}|grep -v grep|cut -c 9-15`
if [ -z "${PID}" ]; then
  echo "Process aready down..."
else
    array=(${PID//\n/})
    for var in "${array[@]}"
    do
      single_pid=`echo ${var} | awk 'gsub(/^ *| *$/,"")' `
      if [[ ${single_pid} -gt 1 ]]; then
          kill -15 "${single_pid}"
      else
          echo "Process ${PROGRAM_NAME} not found"
      fi
    done
fi
```

from the log, I found the pid did not convert to array, the next step did not split correctly. I run this script remotely from GitHub Actions. This is the log output from GitHub Actions:

```
======CMD======
cd /opt/apps/pydolphin
. /opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh

======END======
err: +/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:16> PROGRAM_NAME=schedulespider.py 
err: +/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:17> CELERY_PROGRAM_NAME=celery 
err: +/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:18> PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python3 
err: +/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:23> PID=+/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:23> ps -ef
err: +/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:23> PID=+/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:23> grep -w celery
err: +/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:23> PID=+/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:23> grep -v grep
err: +/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:23> PID=+/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:23> cut -c 9-15
err: +/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:23> PID='  9777 
err:   9778 
err:   9779 
err:   9865 
err:   9867 
err:   9868 ' 
err: +/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:24> [ -z '  9777 
err:   9778 
err:   9779 
err:   9865 
err:   9867 
err:   9868 ' ']'
err: +/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:27> array=( '  9777 
err:   9778 
err:   9779 
err:   9865 
err:   9867 
err:   9868 ' ) 
err: +/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:28> var=  9777 
err:   9778 
err:   9779 
err:   9865 
err:   9867 
err:   9868 
err: +/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:30> single_pid=+/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:30> echo '  9777 
err:   9778 
err:   9779 
err:   9865 
err:   9867 
2021/07/19 06:00:52 Process exited with status 1
err:   9868 '
err: +/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:30> single_pid=+/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:30> awk 'gsub(/^ *| *$/,"")'
err: +/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:30> single_pid='9777
err: 9778
err: 9779
err: 9865
err: 9867
err: 9868' 
err: +/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:31> [[ '9777
err: 9778
err: 9779
err: 9865
err: 9867
err: 9868' -gt 1/opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh:31: bad math expression: operator expected at `9778\n9779\n...'
err:  ]]
```

I read my script and did not found where is going wrong, what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Do you have the `pkill` program available?

Comment: Yes, I could using pkill, but I still want to find where my code going wrong, I want to learn the bash.@JeffSchaller

Comment: Is your interactive shell zsh? I noticed a "`.  /opt/apps/pydolphin/restart.sh`" in your question and steeldriver's answer indicates that zsh could be playing a role. For future questions, be careful you know which shell is executing your code! (and word/tag questions appropriately). Thanks!

Comment: That `xtrace` output format suggests the script is interpreted by `zsh`, not `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are determined to write your own "kill loop" instead of simply using `pkill`, then at least use `pgrep` to get a list of PIDs, unencumbered by possible leading / trailing whitespace - instead of trying to slice and dice the output of `ps`:

```
array=($(pgrep -- "${CELERY_PROGRAM_NAME}"))
```

or simply loop over the `pgrep` output directly

```
for single_pid in $(pgrep -- "${CELERY_PROGRAM_NAME}"); do ...
```

`pgrep` produces a list of PIDs, one per line, and the default bash IFS will split on contiguous whitespace **including newlines** to map them to an array ex.

```
$ pgrep ssh
1194
3688
22642
22754

$ array=($(pgrep ssh))

$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="1194" [1]="3688" [2]="22642" [3]="22754")
```

Alternatively could use `readarray -t array < <(pgrep ssh)`.

There's no need to test for string emptiness since the loop will simply not run if there are no elements.

As to why your implementation is not working, `${PID//\n/}` would remove literal `n` characters from `PID`<sup>1</sup>. Assuming `PID` only contains numeric values, that should do nothing, and `array=(${PID//\n/})` *should* have created an array of individual PIDs, also removing leading and trailing whitespace so that further processing to get a `single_pid` should be unnecessary.

The fact that it apparently doesn't (based on your error output) suggests one of two causes:

1. you have modified the shell's IFS value
2. the shell you are using doesn't word-split unquoted variable expansions. `zsh`, which the format of your `xtrace` output suggests you're using has that default behavior for example, though does IFS-splitting upon command substitution, so the code above would still work in that shell. To split on newline in `zsh`, you'd rather use:

   ```
   array=(${(f)"$(pgrep -- $CELERY_PROGRAM_NAME)"})
   ```

   though, which like `bash`'s `readarray` would remove the dependency on the current value of `$IFS`.

---

<sup>1</sup> to actually remove newlines, you could use `${PID//$'\n'/}`

Answer (score 2):

another alternative to avoid `pgrep/pkill` is to customize `ps`'s output.

`ps` can be customize in both process to list and format/fields to print.

note that `ps -ef` will list all process with many fields, and could be cumbersome to fetch pid.

while `ps -e -o pid,comm` will give a two columns output

```
 PID COMMAND
   1 systemd
   2 kthreadd
   3 rcu_gp
   4 rcu_par_gp
   9 mm_percpu_wq
  10 ksoftirqd/0
    (...)
1002 gdm3
1013 sshd
1031 php-fpm7.4
1032 php-fpm7.4
1044 nginx
1065 nmbd
     (many more lines)
```

(or `-o pid= -o comm=` to remove the headers).

If the process I am looking for is in `${CELERY_PROGRAM_NAME}` (and doesn't contain backslash or blank characters), I can use

```
 ps -e -o pid= -o comm= | awk -v proc="${CELERY_PROGRAM_NAME}" '$2==proc { print $1}'
```

to fetch pids.

using

```
PID=$(ps -e -o pid= -o comm= | awk -v proc="${CELERY_PROGRAM_NAME}" '$2==proc { print $1})
```

after checking non emptiness, and given that `${PID}` is a newline-delimited list of pids, I can use (assuming `$IFS` contains newline as it does by default):

```
for pid2 in ${PID}
do 
   ...
done
```

(if using `zsh` as the format of your `xtrace` output suggests you do, replace `${PID}` with `${=PID}` to do `$IFS`-splitting like `bash` does by default, or with `${(f)PID}` to split on newline regardless of the value of `$IFS`).

### select

some select of `ps` (see `man ps` for all )

- `ps -p 1234 -o tty,args` (list tty and args of pid 1234 )
- `ps -t pts/1,pts/3 -f` (list all from tty pts/1 and pts/3 )
- `ps -u archemar` (list all process belonging to archemar)

The HP/UX and procps implementations of `ps` also support a `-C` option to query processes based on their name.